# No Activity found to handle Intent with action and data

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have written two different Android applications.

I wish for one application to create an intent and in turn, start an activity in the other application.

The first application which creates the intent has the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.example.printtest.ACTION_PRINT");

Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.scheme("PrintAPI")
                .authority("StartPrintJob")
                .appendQueryParameter("appId", "aaa");
Uri uri = builder.build();
intent.setData(uri);

startActivity(intent);
```

The second application which I want to receive the intent has the following defined in it's manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".PrintActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.printtest.ACTION_PRINT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

From what I understand, the activity in the second application should be recognized as the one to start this intent. However, the same exception is thrown each time. The exception being thrown is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 21665
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.printtest.ACTION_PRINT dat=PrintAPI://StartPrintJob?appId=aaa }
```

Is there something that I'm missing?
Is it valid to start an activity in another application just by setting `action` and `data` on an intent?

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you update your question with exception that you are getting?

Comment: Sure thing, question updated.

Comment: check my updated answer, it is  tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to add data part

```
<activity android:name=".PrintActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.printtest.ACTION_PRINT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="PrintAPI"></data>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Unforunately adding `android:exported="true"` doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Comment: @JamesNWarner check by adding data in intent-filter like updated answer.

Comment: Adding data has fixed the issue. Thanks!